# Were Lagrangian coordinates or Eulerian coordinates used first in continuum mechanics?

Tags: physics

In [these lecture notes](http://geo.mff.cuni.cz/vyuka/Martinec-ContinuumMechanics.pdf), I read about two different ways of looking at the position of a particle $\mathcal{X}$ in some body $\mathcal{B}$, [Lagrangian and Eulerian coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_and_Eulerian_specification_of_the_flow_field).

In Lagrangian coordinates, the particle is identified by an ordered triple based on the reference configuration $\kappa_0$. In Eulerian coordinates, the particle is identified by an ordered triple based on the present configuration $\kappa_t$.

While both systems can be used concurrently, and are connected by some useful identities, I'm curious as to which one was used first.